# Module '"tapable"' has no exported member 'Tapable'

Tags: wordpress, typescript, npm, webpack, wordpress-gutenberg

I was working on a WordPress plugin for a custom Gutenberg block.
Since I needed to add additional scripts which I wanted to write in TypeScript, I used "$ tsc --watch" and a "tsconfig.json"-file to compile them.
After installing @wordpress/scripts ("$ npm i --save-dev --save-exact @wordpress/scripts"), tsc indicated 89 errors at this path: node_modules@types\webpack\index.d.ts.

I have opened this file and found that the source of all the errors was the first line of this import statement:

```
import {
  Tapable,
  HookMap,
  SyncBailHook,
  SyncHook,
  SyncLoopHook,
  SyncWaterfallHook,
  AsyncParallelBailHook,
  AsyncParallelHook,
  AsyncSeriesBailHook,
  AsyncSeriesHook,
  AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook,
} from 'tapable';
```

Tsc was still working for my files, but having 89 errors thrown each time I compile is concerning nonetheless.

This is the code of my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "allowUnreachableCode": false,
  "declaration": false,
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "lib": [
    "dom",
    "es2017"
  ],
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "module": "esnext",
  "target": "es2017",
  "outDir": "script/build",
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "noUnusedParameters": true,
  "jsx": "react",
  "jsxFactory": "h"
  },
  "include": [
    "script/src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was the path of the import statement.
Webpack was importing Tapable from node_modules/tapable when it would have needed to import it from node_modules/@types/tapable.

Changing the last line of the import statement fixed all errors:

```
} from '../tapable';
```

Comment: I am still looking for a viable solution to this problem.

This addition to my answer was deleted by a moderator. The code of node modules should never be changed like this. When reinstalling the node modules, installing them on another device or sending the project to another person, they would have to make the same adjustment to the file in the node_modules directory. 

This is a horrible practice.